# onchange event for DOM created inputs and IE 7+8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I am trying to figure out why my javascript that creates input elements on the fly via DOM is referencable in Firefox but not in IE 7 nor 8.

I have the following function triggered when a user clicks a button

```
function addEndPoint_intelDNS(){
    pageCounter.addMethod("endpoint_count");
    count = pageCounter.getendpoint_count();

    //endpoint IP and hostname labels
    var endpointIPText = document.createTextNode('Endpoint ' + count + ' IP: \u00a0');
    var endpointHostText = document.createTextNode('\u00a0 Endpoint ' + count + ' Hostname: \u00a0 ');
    var brNode = document.createElement('br');

    //endpoint InputIPBox
    var endpoint_IP_InputElement = document.createElement('input');
    endpoint_IP_InputElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    endpoint_IP_InputElement.setAttribute('id', 'endpoint_'+count+'_ip');
    endpoint_IP_InputElement.setAttribute('name', 'endpoint_'+count+'_ip');
    endpoint_IP_InputElement.setAttribute('maxlength', '15');
    endpoint_IP_InputElement.setAttribute('onChange', 'resolveMe(this.value,\u0022endpoint_'+count+'_name\u0022, \u0022ip\u0022);');


    //endpoint host inputbox
    var endpoint_HOST_InputElement = document.createElement('input');
    endpoint_HOST_InputElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    endpoint_HOST_InputElement.setAttribute('id', 'endpoint_'+count+'_name');
    endpoint_HOST_InputElement.setAttribute('name', 'endpoint_'+count+'_name');
    endpoint_HOST_InputElement.setAttribute('size', '35');
    endpoint_HOST_InputElement.setAttribute('onChange', 'resolveMe(this.value,\u0022endpoint_'+count+'_ip\u0022, \u0022name\u0022);');

    //output
    document.getElementById('intelDNS_endpoints_codeblock').appendChild(endpointIPText);
    document.getElementById('intelDNS_endpoints_codeblock').appendChild(endpoint_IP_InputElement);
    document.getElementById('intelDNS_endpoints_codeblock').appendChild(endpointHostText);
    document.getElementById('intelDNS_endpoints_codeblock').appendChild(endpoint_HOST_InputElement);
    document.getElementById('intelDNS_endpoints_codeblock').appendChild(brNode);
```

Please ignore the pageCounter object, it is simply an object that keeps track of how many inputs the user will be supplying.

As you can see there is a onChange event attribute added to each of the 2 input text boxes (InputIPBox and host_inputbox) They are practically identical so I will supply one of the functions

```
function resolveMe(val, loc_id, type){
    alert(val);
    switch(type){
        case "ip":
                resolveIP2DNS(val, loc_id);
            break;
        case "name":
                resolveDNS2IP(val, loc_id);
            break;
    }

}

function resolveIP2DNS(ip, loc){
    doclocation = loc;
    var ajaxRequest; //initialize ajax object
    var browser = navigator.appName; //find the browser name
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        /* Create the object using MSIE's method */
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
        /* Create the object using other browser's method */
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            // Get the data from the server's response
            //what on this page is changing
            var xmlRes=ajaxRequest.responseXML.documentElement;
            try {
                var dns = xmlRes.getElementsByTagName('DNS')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            }catch (err){
                dns = "Not Resolvable";
            }
            //output to location in page
            document.getElementById(doclocation).value = dns;   
        }

    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/ajax.psp?ip2DNS=" + ip, true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "text/xml");
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

The ajax.psp page works perfectly and this function works when called for different parts of my site, So i know it is receiving the desired resolution values.

So I am quite stumped, because it works perfectly in Firefox, but not in IE..Also further debuggin I see that the onchange event never goes to the first function in IE(hence the alert never gets popped).

Let me know what you all think...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Internet Explorer doesn't like the "type" attribute to be set after the element is instantiated, but that's probably not your problem in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use "setAttribute()" to set things that should be properties on the DOM node.  Thus, set the "onchange" handler with

```
endpoint_IP_InputElement.onchange = function() {
  resolveMe(this.value, 'endpoint_'+count+'_name', 'ip');
};
```

That will work with Firefox and Chrome etc. too.

*edit* — hold on - we're going to have to make sure `this` is properly bound in the function. I'm not sure it'll be bound automatically in older IE, so I'll check.

*edit again* — yup it should be fine. When your function is called, `this` will be the changed `<input>` node.

Comment: Ok, we are getting somewhere..The auto resolve feautre is working but doesn't line up in the corresponding box. And now when i run the IE debugger the onchange event is not shown in the DOM source code.

Comment: Well I don't know that it'd be shown in the source. There might be another problem in there, of course; this is just what jumped out at me. IE is very particular about the distinction between properties of DOM elements and attributes; they're definitely not the same.

Comment: Even weirder is Firefox still works perfectly with resolutions lining up correctly..

Comment: I think i figured it out..Something with my logic on how i keep track of each row of IP/Hostname. Thanks again for your help Pointy.

Answer (score 0):

```
endpoint_IP_InputElement.onchange = function(){
    resolveMe(this.value,"endpoint_'+count+'_name", "ip");
};
```